# [php]output results of calcualtor on client side only

Tags: php, html, mysql, xhtml

Client code name something like calc.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
</body>

<form action="TESTC.php" method="POST">


<input type="text" name="num1">

<select name="operator">
<option value="+">+</option>
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="*">*</option>
<option value="/">/</option>
</select>


<input type="text" name="num2">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Sever side where the php code is ran is TESTC.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2']) && isset($_POST['operator'])) {

    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
    $operator = $_POST['operator'];

    if (!empty($num1) && !empty ($num2) && !empty($operator)) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'Fill in all fields. ';

    }
}

 if ($operator=='+'){
        echo $num1."+".$num2."=<b>".($num1+$num2)."</b>";
    }
     if ($operator=='-'){
        echo $num1."-".$num2."=<b>".($num1-$num2)."</b>";
    }
     if ($operator=='/'){
        echo $num1."/".$num2."=<b>".($num1/$num2)."</b>";
    }
     if ($operator=='*'){
        echo $num1."*".$num2."=<b>".($num1*$num2)."</b>";
    }   
?>
```

I have this working, but i can only get this code to output on the server side i don't understand correctly how to get the output of the two forms in num1 and num2 to output on the client side page "newCalc.php".  Can someone explain how i can get this to output on one page vs shooting to the TESTC.php once the form is submitted? I can get the html form and the php calculator code working on the one page using both html code and php.  Can someone please help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but that's exactly how you have to do it.

php is not a client-side service. If you want to update the html without posting to the server and rendering a new page, you will need javascript.

Example:

```
// form_template.php
<html><!-- show your form on this page -->
    <form action="calc.php">
    <?php if ($result) echo $result; ?>

// calc.php
<?php // get your POST stuff
    $result = $whatever;
    require_once('form_template.php');

// form.php
<?php // Do defaults here
    $result = false;
    require_once('form_template.php');
```

Comment: Ok that make sense, but how could i output the calculation on the client side?  What your saying is i need a little javascript to output the calculator result on the first page?  I know a little javascript is it alot you have to add to create output function on the client side?

Comment: You will have to echo out the first page contents and the result both.

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: edited answer to show template with 2 files. You could combine calc.php with form.php with a little ingenuity.

Comment: So that code will echo the result on the first page form_template.php?

Comment: calc.php and form.php share form_template.php as a template. Also that code is really crude it won't just run it's only to give you the right idea :)

Answer (score 0):

SOrry to tell you but thats not the way it works, what you should do is send an ajax request to your php script and the update will return the answer you query and echo. It might seem difficult at first but ajax is probably the most useful "language" i have ever learned. as much as i hate `w3schools.com` they do have a very good tutorial on ajax and its relations with PHP [you can find it here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)